# Firebase/Firestore start loop from certain document ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting a collection from my Firestore database and adding the document values to an array in JS:

```
var data = myCollection();

  var myArray = [];

  data.forEach(function(data) {
    var splitPath = data.name.split('/');
    var documentId = splitPath[splitPath.length - 1];
    var name = data.fields.name ? data.fields.name.stringValue : '';
    var country = data.fields.vin ? data.fields.vin.stringValue : '';

    myArray.push( [ documentId, name, country ] );
  });
```

Suppose I know a document ID, is it possible to get the collection documents from that certain document ID?

I'm not sure if Firestore documents are ordered by date. I am trying to get the most recent documents from a certain document ID.

Comment: It depends on the pattern of the document ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I know a document ID, is it possible to get the collection documents from that certain document ID?

When it comes to the Firebase console, all documents are sorted [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) by ID and this behavior can't be changed. When it comes to code, it's up to you to choose how to order the results.

> I'm not sure if Firestore documents are ordered by date.

No, there is no time component inside the document IDs.

> I am trying to get the most recent documents from a certain document ID.

In that case, the simplest solution would be to add a timestamp field in each document and order them according to that field.

However, Firebase Realtime Database pushed IDs do contain a time component. So if you want, you can add that data there. Both databases are working great together.

If you have multiple documents and you want to implement [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), for example, you can use query cursors and use `startAt()` or `starAfter()` if you need that.

Comment: Thank you! I actually am storing a date in the Firestore documents. The date has this format `2022-07-18 15:59:28` maybe I can use that to sort.

Comment: The best practice is to save the date as a timestamp, but it can work with something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need but firebase docs has below example:[Order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

```
import { query, where, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";  

const q = query(citiesRef, where("population", ">", 100000), orderBy("population"), limit(2));
```

if you adjust where part to your id, then sort by date it should work.